# QT QCustomPlot in a new thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qcustomplot

In my UI, I have a `QCustomPlot` and I have `generatePlot` function which uses from this `QCustomPlot` and runs in a new thread as follows:

```
future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MainWindow::generatePlot);
```

In `generatePlot` function, I create `QCPbars` like this:

```
QCPBars *bar = new QCPBars(customPlot->xAxis, customPlot->yAxis);
```

But, I get this **error**:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

I think that's because the thread of `customPlot` is diffrenet from `bar`.
How can I solve it?

Comment: You should create a Worker class for this processing and not do that in a MainWindow method. Also this code is probably not what you have, it should not compile : `QCPBars bar = new QCPBars` please give more details.

Comment: @ymoreau thanks, yes, I'm sorry, I changed my code to be here more obviously. I modified it.
Original command was:
`QCPBars *bars[plotsNum_+1];` and in the `for` `bars[i] = new QCPBars(customPlot->xAxis, customPlot->yAxis);`
Did you mean that I should create a new class which has inherited from `QThread`

Comment: No, inheriting from `QThread` is not the recommended practice, `QtConcurrent` is probably the best choice in your case, keep this. But you could create a dedicated class that contains the method `generatePlot` and the `bars` array and any related data, so you do not mess up with `MainWindow` data-members and methods, you isolate the code to run concurrently.

Comment: About your error message, it is not allowed to create a child `QObject` in a different thread-context than its parent, you will need to post more code, where could you set a parent to a new object in your theaded-code ?

Comment: @ymoreau  But I have a `QCustomPlot` in one of my UI tabs, which I have to use that in `generatePlot` function, so in that dedicated class as you mentioned I have to get that `QCustomPlot` and this problem will happen again...

Comment: Please edit et explain your exact design, what objects and parenting you have

Comment: @ymoreau thanks, let me explain mush more:
I have a pushbutton that: 
`on_plot_pushButton_clicked` function has following code in it:
`future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MainWindow::generatePlot);`. In `MainWindow::generatePlot` I have the following code: `GenPlot::getInstance()->generatePlot(ui->plot_widget);` which `ui->plot_widget` is `QCustomPlot` and in `GenPlot::generatePlot` I have `QCPBars` and so on...
Now as a trick I use `ui->plot_widget=GenPlot::getInstance()->generatePlot()` and return `QcustomPlot` from `GenPlot::generatePlot` and replace with `ui->plot_widget` with no error

Comment: @ymoreau But my `ui->plot_widget` does not update even though I use `QCustomPlot::replot()` or `QCustomPlot::update()`. Why not update the `ui->plot_widget`?

Comment: Put the info in the question please ! The purpose is to make it clear for everyone who might read it, without reading the comments.

Comment: @ymoreau thank you, I created a new simpler question here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345789/qt-qcustomplot-parent]
If you can't answer that, I edit this post and post my real code here.
Thanks again...

Comment: You could show the code of the method that takes a long time, maybe you are implementing it in an incorrect way.The solution is not always to use a new thread, that is to abuse the resources.