# QT QCustomPlot parent

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I have a `QCustomPlot` widget in my ui as follows:

```
ui->plot_widget
```

also I have another `QCustomPlot` object in my cpp file as follows:

```
QCustomPlot *plot=new QCustomPlot();
```

I want to add `plot` data into `ui->plot_widget` data.
If I use `ui->plot_widget=plot` the widget parent of `ui->plot_widget` will be destroyed and my ui does not update `ui->plot_widget`.

How can I add `plot` data into `ui->plot_widget` data?

Comment: Why do you want to add a QCustomPlot to another QCustomPlot?, Use: `ui->plot_widget->addGraph()` after: `ui->graph(0)->setData(your_x_data, your_y_data)`, read this: http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/basicplotting

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, I have a function that returns a `QCustomPlot` object and I want to show that plot in my ui. I check it and reply

Comment: QCustomPlot is a widget that handles several plots.

Comment: You have a bad design then, think and redesign your code.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks, I have a problem in using `QCustomPlot` in a new thread, so to solving I use a trick and explained here. Can you see this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337058/qt-qcustomplot-in-a-new-thread]

Comment: @eyllanesc because my plot takes a long time and I want to show in status bar a loading gif and also I want to have a responsible ui

Comment: I have a class that generates the plot and computing the data of the plot takes too long